# Tag merge suggestion: [programs] and [programming]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programs) has a short description:

> Plans, guidelines and schedules for training and eating.

The tag [programming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) doesn't have any description, but both tags are used in questions about programming anyway. I'd suggest merging both and we can add a better description fitting the tag (I vote for keeping [programming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) because it also describes creating / structuring / critiquing / selecting programs).

Comment: +1, I've got no problem with that. I can add `programs` in as a synonym for `programming` and update the description for `programming` as well. I will check back on this in a few days and, unless it goes negative, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should now be completed. Questions that are tagged as `programs` should now be directed to `programming`. I took an initial stab at the [tag usage excerpt](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) and the [tag wiki](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tags/programming/info).

Please feel free to make and/or suggest edits as you see fit. If that's not something a user has enough reputation to do just ping me in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room).